# CSS Grid layout can't get layout to behave the way I want no matter what I do

Tags: html, css, grid, grid-layout

Hey guys so im trying to do this assignment and one of the requirements is that it uses a grid layout in CSS so I have put together just the beginning of the page trying to get the layout to work the way I  want it to and for the life of me I can't get this page to behave the way I need and it's driving me up the wall that I can't figure out what I am doing wrong or missing on this. I have looked at so many guides and sites on how to use grid and I am just not sure what I am missing. Any help is really appreciated here's my code.
*Edit*
The layout that I am aiming towards is something like this.[image]

HTML

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Assignment 3</title>
<meta name="description" content="This is the assignment 3 web page showcasing what we have learned in COMP1223 the so far.">
<meta name="keywords" content="Assignment 3, HTML5, CSS, flexbox, grid, form, image mapping, position fixed, nav">
<meta name="author" content="Jessica">
<link href="grid.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>


<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item">
        <aside class="hobbies">1</aside>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
        <header class="intro">2</header>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
        <section class="application">3</section>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
        <section class="form_elements">4</section>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
        <article class="tutorial">5</article>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
        <footer class="image_mapping">6</footer>
    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(5 auto);
    background-color: #2196F3;
    padding: 10px;
    grid-template-areas: "hb int int" "hb app fe" "hb app fe" "tu tu tu" "im im im";
}

.grid-item {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

.hobbies {
    grid-area: hb;
}

.intro {
    grid-area: int;
}

.application {
    grid-area: app;
}

.form_elements {
    grid-area: fe;
}

.tutorial {
    grid-area: tu;
}

.image_mapping {
    grid-area: im;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that you are assigning the grid-areas to the 'aside', 'header' and stuff, while you should be assigning the same grid-areas to the div's that are containing them.

One tip, if you are going to use 'aside' and stuff, you should not put them into div's because div and aside do the same thing, they group content.

I will leave how i would do that assignament so maybe it will helps you in the future:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "hb int int"
    "hb ma ma"
    "ar ar ar"
    "im im im";
  /*I give the rows and columns a size just for comfort, but you can use '1fr'*/
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 100px);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 100px);
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-item,  .grid-main-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

/*I use id's to be more specific in wich thing i want to assign wich grid-area*/

#hobbies {
  grid-area: hb;
}

#intro {
  grid-area: int;
}

#tutorial {
  grid-area: ar;
}

#image_mapping {
  grid-area: im;
}


/* main container to have that 2 section's inside another block*/
#main-container {
  grid-area: ma;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "app frm"
    "app frm";
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    /*you can put padding: 0; so the main container is invisible*/
}

#application {
  grid-area: app;
}

#form_elements {
  grid-area: frm;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">

    <header class="grid-item" id="intro">2</header>

    <aside class="grid-item" id="hobbies">1</aside>

  <main class="grid-item" id="main-container">
    <section class="grid-main-item" id="application">3</section>

    <section class="grid-main-item" id="form_elements">4</section>

</main>
    <article class="grid-item" id="tutorial">5</article>
  

    <footer class="grid-item" id="image_mapping">6</footer>

</div>
```

Comment: ok thank you so much for the help and also for the tip new to html and css and coding in general so still learning all of it thanks again. :)

Comment: you are welcome :), there i have just left a way to do it with some comments...

Comment: one more question for you as you seem very knowledgeable in this subject. If I wanted to put a nav menu in the top of the page position fixed would I want to place that inside the grid container or outside of it?

Comment: popularly, the nav is used inside the header because the header and the nav are usually at the top of the page. What you can do is put that header/nav outside the grid container, style it so make it fixed at the top of the page, and style the grid container with some margin-top: {"height of the nav";}

Answer (score 1):

Here is another implementation, maybe easier to understand

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>

        * {
            padding: 40px;
        }
        body {
            background-color: rgb(61, 61, 61);
        }
        .container{
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
            gap: 10px;
        }

        .container > div {
            border-style: solid;
        }

        .aside {
            grid-row: 1 / 3;
        }

        .header {
            grid-column: 2 / 4
        }

        .article, .section {
            grid-column: 1 / 4;
        }
    </style>


    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="aside">aside</div>
        <div class="header">header</div>
        <div>section</div>
        <div>section</div>
        <div class="article">article </div>
        <div class="section">section</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Check out the demo: https://codepen.io/anthony_718/pen/dyppJwd

Resource for understanding CSS Grid:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/getting-started-with-css-grid-layout